# Fetch field inside a collection in firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to fetch the fields inside the subcollection but it is returning "undefined" and the database is designed like this:

- Collection
- Document
- Collection
- Document
- Field

[image]

here is the code:

```
 const getEventInfo = async () => {
 await firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("events/" + eventId + "/agenda")
  .doc(customerCollectionIds)
  .get()
  .then((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data())
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Awit Error getting document:", error)
  })
```

}

I am using reactjs. what am I missing here?

Comment: Does `console.log(doc.data())` show your desired output?

Comment: @Stratubas no, it says undefined. but whenever I call the root path which is ".collection("events/")", it is working. just an issue with subcollection or something I think

Comment: Are you sure that `customerCollectionIds` is not undefined/null? And what do you see in the `catch((error)` block?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yes man, I am 100% sure. I had to console.log twice and even thrice just to make sure. But all of them returns undefined, the catch (error) block doesn't return anything. so I am guessing that the code works? just something is missing? maybe a path? not really sure  on that part :(

Comment: @RenaudTarnec sorry! totally misunderstood your question. but customerCollectionIds is not undefined/null. I had to double check it on my firestore console.

Comment: Show us screenshots of your database from firebase console, plus how `customerCollectionIds` gets its value.

Comment: @sam Is there any security rule that prevent reading the docs? (You should normally see an error if it is the case but it worth asking IMO)